# Módulo rewrite em .htaccess para sub pastas

Tags: apache, htaccess

Tenho uma aplicação em `AngularJs` com `html5` habilitado, o que faz com que eu precise utilizar o módulo `rewrite` do apache para que haja a conversão correta da URL.

Não tenho problema algum para utilizar isso quando acessando a aplicação com o index a partir da raiz, ou seja, se eu acessar `www.meusite.com.br` e navegar pelos menus, atualizar a página, etc.. tudo funciona corretamente.

O problema começa quando preciso acessar uma nova área do `app` que inicia em uma sub pasta, por exemplo, minha área administrativa. Ela fica toda armazenada em uma sub pasta chamada `adm` sendo acessada assim: `www.meusite.com.br/adm`

Nessa sub pasta adm, tenho um novo index, novas sub pastas, etc.. Uma nova área do `app` focada somente na administração e é nessa parte que estou com problemas ao utilizar o módulo `rewrite` com `html5`, pois ao atualizar a página ele não encontra mais o caminho, no caso, ele tenta iniciar a partir do index da raiz.

Esse é meu arquivo `.htaccess` localizado na raiz do `app`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Em teoria sei que precisaria de uma regra que aponte para a sub pasta também, mas não sei como criar essa regra e também não consegui encontrar nada até o momento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você terá que criar outro `.htacess`, salvá-lo na pasta `adm` e mudar a segunda e a última linha:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /adm
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /adm/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Nesse caso, a "raiz" ficará apontada para o `/adm` (segunda linha) e ao entrar na raiz, vai procurar o `index.html` (última linha).

Comment: mas isso não irá 'sobrescrever' o que foi definido no outro .htaccess ? Por que eu preciso acessar as duas áreas de modo igual. Ou esse htaccess seria para colocar dentro da sub pasta 'adm' ?

Comment: Esse tu cria dentro da subpasta. Nesse caso não vai interferir um no outro.

Comment: Ainda assim, o primeiro acesso é ok, mas quando atualizo a página ele volta para o index localizado na raiz, não na pasta 'adm'

Comment: Isso, coloquei esse da sua resposta dentro da pasta adm e mantive o da minha questão na pasta raiz.

Comment: mudei a ultima linha, veja se da certo agora.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado! Havia tentado algo semelhante a isso, mas não compreendo a lógico correta dos arquivos htaccess, agora já ficou mais claro o funcionamento também, vlw!